# Is it possible to find the LLVM version from textual LLVM IR .ll file?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, bitcode

I have several .ll files containing LLVM IR code in textual form. I want to filter the files depending on their LLVM version for example I would like to find all the files that use LLVM version 3-7.

Currently, I have tried to convert .ll file to .bc file using llvm-as tool and tried using llvm-bcanalyzer to get some useful information such as the required version number but it seems that I was mistaken and llvm-bcanalyzer does not provide such information.

So is there any way to find out which version of LLVM was used to write a given .ll file?

Comment: No, but have a look at [the file format specification](https://llvm.org/docs/BitCodeFormat.html) if you want, it's interesting on its own right. IIRC there also isn't any way to write that using DWARF.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the version of the entire LLVM toolchain will be same as version of the clang used to generate the .ll file, as clang is a part of LLVM toolchain only.

Just open the .ll file and search `clang version` and you will be able to find something like `clang version 12.0.0`